# Autocomplete scala match case in Intellij

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

in the past I had intellij do awsome autocomplete of cases when matching any sealed trait (e.g. `Option`) but can't get it to work on my new setup and can't find anything online, any ideas on where to look, what is the setting name etc?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I missed this feature, it used to work by pressing Alt+Enter then selecting "Generate case clauses"

Now you can achieve the same while typing `myValue mat...` then you can choose `match (exhaustive)`